# pdftoppmで出力した文字列が文字化けする

Tags: pdf

**updated:**

xpdfの [pdftoppm](http://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftoppm-man.html) を使ってPDFからppmファイルを出力する際、PDFファイルに含まれている文字列の一部が文字化けしてしまいます。文字列は以下のような感じです。

```
A̲30̲12̲03̲9995
```

アンダースコアのように見えるのは発音区別符号です(utf8コードの0x332)。これはエンコードエラーかフォントのマッピングエラーでしょうか？

pdftoppm: 4.01.01
ubuntu: 18.04.2 LTS

実行コマンド:

```
pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 sample.pdf sample
```

xpdfファイルの設定:

```
textEncoding UTF-8
fontDir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
cidToUnicode Adobe-Japan1 /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/Adobe-Japan1.cidToUnicode
unicodeMap ISO-2022-JP /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/ISO-2022-JP.unicodeMap
unicodeMap EUC-JP /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/EUC-JP.unicodeMap
unicodeMap Shift-JIS /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/Shift-JIS.unicodeMap
cMapDir Adobe-Japan1 /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/CMap
toUnicodeDir /usr/local/share/xpdf/japanese/CMap

fontFile   MSPGothic     /usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-gothic/ipagp.ttf
```

pdffontsコマンドによる文字列情報:

```
$ pdffonts sample.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni prob object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---- ---------
MSPGothic                            CID TrueType      no  no  no   X       15  0
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　この問題を再現するような（できれば小さな）PDFファイルと、それをPPMに変換するために質問者さんが実行した具体的なコマンドを示していただくことは可能ですか？　質問文下の「編集」から追記して頂ければと思います。

Comment: PDFファイルは情報保護のため添付できませんでしたが、実行コマンドを追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これは対応するフォントが存在しないことによる不具合でした。
xpdfrcファイルにはノーマルなIPAゴシックのフォントを適用していましたが、ダイアクリティカルマーク(発音区別符号)の0x0332に対応するフォントがなかったようです。
適用するフォントを該当文字を含むIPAexゴシック、NotoSans、 Arial Unicode MSなどに変更したら文字が表示されました。